# How can I get particular data from a nested JSON in Laravel using Hasone?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel_Framework_5.4.28.

I am trying to compare the Empid from the user collection to the team collection, so that I will get the user name and other details.

Please help me to solve this one.

```
//laravel model.

class team_model extends Eloquent
{

       protected $collection = 'team';


     public function  team_r_ship()

     {  
        return $this->hasone('App\User','Empid','members.Empid');
}



}
```

My JSON data is given below:

```
// collection: team

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5993e71c44c7c122e43851d2"),
        "members" : [
            {
                "position" : "designer",
                "Empid" : "Emp_0001"
            },
            {
                "position" : "developer",
                "Empid" : "Emp_0002"
            },
            {
                "position" : "developer",
                "Empid" : "Emp_0003"
            }
        ],
        "t_name" : "team A",
        "team_type" : "offical",
        "teamhead" : "Emp_0001"
    }
```

Comment: App\User is a collection which also has  Empid in it . all i want is to compare the Empid with user collection                                                                                                                          <?php
namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use App\User;



class team_model extends Eloquent
{
   


       protected $collection = 'team';


     public function  team_r_ship()

     {
          

  return $this->hasone('App\User','Empid','members.Empid');

}

public function team_r_ship_second()
{

 
}

Comment: I am using Eloquent in the project .